# Чем заменить словосочетание «словесная обструкция»?

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов, семантика, синонимы

Каким словом описать ситуацию, когда человеку публично (т.е. в присутствии ещё хотя бы одного человека) говорят, что он сделал что-то плохое?

Первое, что приходит на ум, — «словесная обструкция», но это кажется каким-то неточным, это больше применимо, например, к воспрепятствованию публичному выступлению.

Ругают? Травят? А если это единичный случай? (Травля, в моём понимании, длится во времени.)

Ставят на вид? Стыдят?

Какие ещё есть варианты?..

Comment: Обличение? Вернее, публичное обличение.

Comment: Тогда уж «осуждение», но как по мне, всё равно не то.

Comment: Есть ещё слово: порицание. Есть выговор, но это более официальный термин.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь о ситуационной критике человека (за его слова/поступки), то, возможно, подойдут такие слова.

1. **Распекание** (от **распекать** — делать кому-либо строгий выговор, отчитывать; см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)).
2. **Журение** (от **журить** — слегка выговаривать кому-либо; выражать порицание; см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)).
3. **Укорение** (от **укорять** — упрекать, порицать за что-либо; см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)).

Comment: Распекать, для моего случая, звучит неплохо :)

Comment: И отчитывать - тоже неплохо.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно существительное, то у Достоевского есть слово *распеканция*: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1001958

И ещё есть существительное (!) *нагоняй*. И *разнос*.

Comment: О, спасибо! А также взбучка и наезд. Интересно, а есть ли подобное слово, но с намёком на несправедливость? Может, как раз наезд?

Comment: Я согласен: с намёком на несправедливость это как раз наезд.